# how to split text in console into separate arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Code:

```
message.member.voice.channel.join();
let VC = message.member.voice.channel

message.channel.send(VC.members.map(member => member.id))
console.log(VC.members.map(member => member.id))
```

Console:

```
[ '123...', '456...', '789...' ]
```

Discord:

```
123...
456...
789...
```

I need:

```
[ '123...' ]
[ '456...' ]
[ '789...' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there:

```js
VC = {
  members: [{
    id: '123...'
  }, {
    id: '456...'
  }, {
    id: '789...'
  }]
};
console.log(VC.members.map(member => [member.id]));

// or:

VC.members.map(member => console.log([member.id])); // suggested by @vaku
```

Comment: What about `VC.members.map(member => console.log([member.id]));` ?